# Foreign key value is not getting saved in hibernate in Child table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have master and child table in the MS sql server. I have a foreign key reference in the child table. 
But still association is not getting established, value is getting null.

So I have 'Student' table and 'AcademicInfo' table. Following are its columns.

Student ->  [StudentId, Name,Surname, City]

AcademicInfo -> [Id, StudentIdentity,Subject, Year]

Now, my foreign key is in child table that is AcademicInfo(StudentIdentity) with column StudentId of parent Student.

My case is of one to one relationship as one Student can only have one subject (just for exercise purpose)

AcademicInfo.java

```js
package com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="AcademicInfo")
public class AcademicInfo {
 
 public AcademicInfo()
 {}


 public AcademicInfo(String subject, Integer year) {  
  Subject = subject;
  Year = year;
 }


 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
 @Column(name="Id")
 private int Id;
 
 

 @Column(name="Subject")
 public String Subject;
 
 @Column(name="Year")
 public Integer Year;

 public int getId() {
  return Id;
 }

 public void setId(int id) {
  Id = id;
 }

 public String getSubject() {
  return Subject;
 }

 public void setSubject(String subject) {
  Subject = subject;
 }

 public Integer getYear() {
  return Year;
 }

 public void setYear(Integer year) {
  Year = year;
 }


 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "AcademicInfo [Id=" + Id  + ", Subject=" + Subject + ", Year=" + Year + "]";
 }
 
 
 @OneToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.REFRESH})
 @JoinColumn(name="StudentIdentity")
 private Student studentInfo;

 public Student getStudentInfo() {
  return studentInfo;
 }


 public void setStudentInfo(Student studentInfo) {
  this.studentInfo = studentInfo;
 }

 
}
```

Student.java

```js
package com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity;
import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name="StudentDetails")
public class Student {
 
 public Student()
 {}

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
 @Column(name="StudentID")
 private int StudentID;
 

 
 @Column(name="Name")
 public String StudentName;
 

 @Column(name="Surname")
 public String Surname;
 
 @Column(name="City")
 public String City;
 
 public int getStudentID() {
  return StudentID;
 }

 
 
 
 public void setStudentID(int studentID) {
  StudentID = studentID;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return StudentName;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  StudentName = name;
 }

 public String getSurname() {
  return Surname;
 }

 public void setSurname(String surname) {
  Surname = surname;
 }

 public String getCity() {
  return City;
 }

 public void setCity(String city) {
  City = city;
 }

 

 public Student(String name, String surname, String city) {  
  StudentName = name;
  Surname = surname;
  City = city;
 }

 
 
 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "Student [StudentID=" + StudentID + ", StudentName=" + StudentName + ", Surname=" + Surname + ", City="
    + City + "]";
 }

 @OneToOne(mappedBy="studentInfo",cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.REFRESH})
 private AcademicInfo academicDetails;

 public AcademicInfo getAcademicDetails() {
  return academicDetails;
 }


 public void setAcademicDetails(AcademicInfo academicDetails) {
  this.academicDetails = academicDetails;
 }

 
 


 
 
 
}
```

Main App

```js
package com.luv2code.hibernate.newDemo;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity.AcademicInfo;
import com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.entity.Student;

public class CreateStudentDemo {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                     .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                     .addAnnotatedClass(AcademicInfo.class)
                     .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                     .buildSessionFactory();
  
  Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
  
  session.beginTransaction();
  
  Student theStudent1 = new Student("Andy","test","NY");
  AcademicInfo stuAcademics = new AcademicInfo("OS", 2001);
    
  theStudent1.setAcademicDetails(stuAcademics);
  
  System.out.println(theStudent1);

  session.save(stuAcademics);
  
  session.getTransaction().commit();
  
  
  try {
   
  }
  finally {
   factory.close();
  }
   
  
 }

}
```

Following is the "hibernate.cfg.xml"

```js
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=India;integratedSecurity=true</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password">Temp1234</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">100</property>

        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</property>

        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

  <!-- Set the current session context -->
  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
 
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

It throws the error as follows:
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'StudentIdentity', table 'dbo.AcademicInfo'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
If i have declared the association, why studentId is not getting inserted automatically ?

Comment: What Hibernate version are you using?

Comment: Hibernate version is 5.3

Comment: try to change `GenerationType.IDENTITY` to `GenerationType.AUTO`